# Regex: get subdomain or domain but not www

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to create a regex that captures a subdomain, not www, or the domain.

So, it should be able to match
client.com => client
subdomain.client.com => subdomain
www.client.com => client

But I have some trouble eliminating the optional www with a lookahead.

Currently, I have this:

```
/((?!www)([^\.]+)\.)?([^\.]+)\.(?:(co?|nl|be|fr|de|es|it|pt|gov|org)).*/
```

https://regex101.com/r/d4qPNV/2

but I can't seem to eliminate the www capture. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`((?!w+)([^\.]+)\.)?([^\.]+)\.(?:(co?|nl|be|fr|de|es|it|pt|gov|org)).*`

If you don't care about excluding subdomains that would be "wwwwww" and the like.

or

`([^w{3}+]+\.)?([^\.]+)\.(?:(co?|nl|be|fr|de|es|it|pt|gov|org)).*`

If you really only want it to exclude "www".

Comment: I'm currently using 

`^(?:(?!w{3})([^.]+)\.)(?:([^.]+)\.)?([^.]+)\.(?:(com?\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2,3}))$`

to match
`client.mydomain.com => client`
`client.acc.mydomain.com => client`
`www.mydomain.com => mydomain`

It's not capturing the mydomain and making it optional:
`^(?:(?!w{3})([^.]+)\.)?(?:([^.]+)\.)?([^.]+)\.(?:(com?\.[a-z]{2}|[a-z]{2,3}))$`

makes it capture `www`.